# Evaluate the Integral: $\int(x^5+5^x)\ dx$

Tags: calculus

$\int(x^5+5^x)\ dx$

I made the the terms within the parenthesis u

$u=x^5+5^x$

$du=5x^4+5^xln\ 5$

$du=5x^4+5^x\ ln\ 5 dx$

$\frac{u}{5x^4+5^xln\ 5}\ du$

I am stuck at this point. Is there a better way to attack this problem? I know I have to use this formula

> $\int\ a^x dx=\frac{a^x}{ln\ a}+C$

But how?

Comment: You can split in sum of two integrals.

Comment: Congrats on five identical answers :)

Comment: @theage well, the average person on this site knows basically nothing beyond calculus, so this 5 answers per one question scheme makes sense. A possible solution is to create a third site for people MSE and MO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to evaluate this integral, you should simplify like this:

$\int{(x^5 + 5^x) dx} = \int{x^5 dx} + \int{5^x dx}$. You can always split up an expression of the same variable like this to simplify your computation. Now, generally, $\int{x^ndx} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} +C$, and $\int{a^xdx} = \frac{a^x}{ln{(a)}} +C$.

So, our result is: $\int{x^5 dx} + \int{5^x dx} = \frac{x^6}{6} + \frac{5^x}{ln{(5)}} +C$. $C$ is the constant of integration, due to the integral being indefinite.

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated. You just need to use the rules
$$
\int x^n \; dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1} + C\\
$$
and
$$
\int a^x \; dx= \frac{1}{\ln(a)}a^x + C.
$$
So
$$
\int x^5 + 5^x \; dx = \int x^5 \; dx + \int 5^x \; dx = ...
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You integral is a sum:
$$
\int (x^5+5^x)dx=\int x^5 dx+\int 5^x dx
$$
now use $5=e^{log 5}$ and you have:
$$
\int x^5 dx+\int e^{xlog 5} dx
$$

can you integrate this?

Comment: (+1) change the $\log$ with $\ln$, it is more correct

Comment: It's not 'more correct', @Cardinal. If anything, $\log$ representing the natural logarithm is more commonplace in mathematics.

Comment: I prefer to use $\log$ for natural logarithm , $\mbox{Log}$ for base $10 $ and specify the basis $\log_a$ if it is different. But it is a matter of convenction and mybe That my convenction is old or only italian. :)

Comment: I was thinking about $x=e^{\ln x}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\int (x^5+5^x)dx$$ $$=\int x^5 dx+\int 5^x dx$$ $$=\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{5^x}{\ln 5}+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Split the integral into two: $$\int x^5 \mathrm {d}x +\int5^x \mathrm {d}x$$ and evaluate them.$$\int x^5 \mathrm {d}x=\frac{x^6}{6}$$ and $$\int5^x \mathrm {d}x=\frac{5^x}{\mathrm {ln} 5}$$ then add them together to get the answer: $$\int x^5 \mathrm {d}x +\int5^x \mathrm {d}x=\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{5^x}{\mathrm {ln} 5}+C$$